# Расстановка переносов в тексте для java или на android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите какой-нибудь фреймворк для расстановки переносов в тексте, или хотя бы мог возвращать варианты переноса по скармливаемому слову. Без разницы будет он использовать для этого интернет или нет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант, можно попробовать TeXHyphenator-J ( http://www.davidashen.net/texhyphj.html) или Hyphenation ( https://bitbucket.org/feuervogel/hyphenation/src ).

Comment: Да, спасибо. TeXHyphenator-J я вчера нашел и уже потестил, выдает местами странные переносы и с кириллицей он у меня пока не завёлся. Второй вариант проверю, отпишусь. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: если не получается запустить с кириллицей TeXHyphenator-J , то можете еще написать в это сообщество http://tex.stackexchange.com, там точно должны помочь, скорее всего там нужно импортировать словарь, что бы поддерживалась кириллица.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Запустил TeXHyphenator-J и с кириллицей, там из-за реализации только под Latin-1 кодировку были проблемы, но и метод для загрузки массива кодировки для киррилицы есть. Файл с кодами и таблицей для кириллице в Latin-1 кодировке есть. Все работает, выдает приличные результаты))) Уже прикрутил)

Comment: Отлично, рада, что все работает!